# How can I get a string of other language by Unicode string. My program get different result by the same input? Is there something ignore

Tags: java, string, unicode

```
    Charset cs = Charset.forName("UTF-16");
    String s = "\u041c\u0435\u043d\u044f \u0437\u043e\u0432\u0443\u0442 \u0438\u0437 \u041a\u0435\u0439\u043d";
    System.out.println(cs.decode(cs.encode(s))); // why this line can print the specific language string
    for(String s1 : res){
        System.out.println(s1);
        System.out.println(cs.decode(cs.encode(s1)));//But this line can not
    }
```

the flowing is my result:

> Меня зовут из Кейн
>   \u041c\u0435\u043d\u044f \u0437\u043e\u0432\u0443\u0442 \u0438\u0437 \u041a\u0435\u0439\u043d
>   \u041c\u0435\u043d\u044f \u0437\u043e\u0432\u0443\u0442 \u0438\u0437 \u041a\u0435\u0439\u043d
>   \u042f \u0438\u0437 \u043a\u0438\u0442\u0430\u044f
>   \u042f \u0438\u0437 \u043a\u0438\u0442\u0430\u044f
>   \u043c\u043e\u0435\u0433\u043e \u0441\u044b\u043d\u0430 \u0437\u043e\u0432\u0443\u0442 \u0425\u0443\u0430\u043d
>   \u043c\u043e\u0435\u0433\u043e \u0441\u044b\u043d\u0430 \u0437\u043e\u0432\u0443\u0442 \u0425\u0443\u0430\u043d
>
> I wonder if there some difference between s and s1?

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to achieve, but it's important to understand that encodings aren't "languages". It doesn't help that we know nothing about what `res` is, either.

Comment: ArrayList<String> res = new ArrayList<String>();

Comment: Also note that `s` contains characters U+041C, U+0435 etc, with no backslashes and no `u` characters. Your other strings - wherever they've come from - appear to be escape sequences.

Comment: And that comment only shows an empty array list, which clearly isn't what you've actually got. Please provide a [mcve] and read https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/ for information about how to write a clear, good question.

Comment: Your question is very unclear, but if you want to check if there is any difference between s and s1, just use s.equals(s1), and you'll know.

Comment: Thank you!  s1 is a String which has a same format with s. And I want to know why **System.out.println(cs.decode(cs.encode(s1)))** can't  print the String similar as Меня зовут из Кейн

Comment: "Thank you! s1 is a String which has a same format with s." No, it looks like it's a string containing backslashes and `u` characters etc - it's an *escaped* string. Whereas `s` doesn't have any of those - the escape characters in your string literal are handled by the Java compiler, and don't exist at execution time. Unfortunately we have no idea where you've read the string from or why you expect to use a `Charset` to do anything in this case, so it's hard to help you. If you'd provided more context, it would be a lot easier to help you.

Comment: {"from":"zh","to":"ru","trans_result":[{"src":"\u6211\u53eb\u4ece\u575a","dst":"\u041c\u0435\u043d\u044f \u0437\u043e\u0432\u0443\u0442 \u0438\u0437 \u041a\u0435\u0439\u043d"},{"src":"\u6211\u6765\u81ea\u4e2d\u56fd","dst":"\u042f \u0438\u0437 \u043a\u0438\u0442\u0430\u044f"},{"src":"\u6211\u7684\u513f\u5b50\u53eb\u9ec4\u51ef","dst":"\u043c\u043e\u0435\u0433\u043e \u0441\u044b\u043d\u0430 \u0437\u043e\u0432\u0443\u0442 \u0425\u0443\u0430\u043d"}]}.. I get the _res_ from such text. and it's a translate program.  So I need to convert the String like \u.... to a text of language.

Comment: And the ' s ' is my test string.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote an open source library that contains a Utility that allows you to convert any string to Unicode sequence and vice-versa. You might find it useful. You can do:

```
String s = StringUnicodeEncoderDecoder.encodeStringToUnicodeSequence("Hello world")
```

And it will give you String: "\u0048\u0065\u006c\u006c\u006f\u0020\u0077\u006f\u0072\u006c\u0064" and then you can do this:

```
    String s 
= StringUnicodeEncoderDecoder.decodeUnicodeSequenceToString("\u0048\u0065\u006c\u006c\u006f\u0020\u0077\u006f\u0072\u006c\u0064");
```

And it will return you String "Hello world". It may help you understand how things work with Unicode encoding. It works with any language. Here is the link to the article that explains where to get the library: [Open Source Java library with stack trace filtering, Silent String parsing Unicode converter and Version comparison](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/open-source-java-library-some-useful-utilities-michael-gantman) Look for paragraph titled "**String Unicode converter**"